# How to insert multiple images with different color for single product in PHP and MYSql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert multiple images for a product according to different colors, But I am unable to insert multiple images in a single row with color_id.

Here is the image of color and images section

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div id="paramsFields" class="color_wrapper row">
        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class="col-form-label">Product Color</label>
            <select class="form-control  bg-indigo-400 rounded-round" name="color[]">
                <option>Select Color</option>
                <?php foreach ($color as $col) {

                    ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $col->id ?>">
                    <?php echo $col->color_name ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3">
            <label class="col-form-label ">Product Image</label>
            <input type="file" id="paramFieldValue" class="form-control rounded-round" name="images[0][]" multiple>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            <label class="col-form-label ">Add More</label>
            <button type="button" class="add btn bg-teal-400 btn-labeled btn-labeled-left rounded-round"><b><i
                        class="icon-add"></i></b> Add</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Color Input :]

Here is my table

I want to insert images in a single row for a particular color_id for the same product.

[image: Color and Image Table]

Here is my PHP Code

```
if (is_post_request()) {
$product_id =   8;

    $color = $_POST['color'];
    $col = '';
    $size_str = '';
    if ($color != '') {
        $targetDir = "../assets/main/color_images/";
        $allowTypes = array('jpg', 'png', 'jpeg', 'gif');
        $statusMsg = $errorMsg = $insertValuesSQL = $errorUpload = $errorUploadType = '';

        foreach ($color as $c => $k) {

            foreach ($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key => $value) {

                if ($c === $key) {

                    foreach ($value as $i => $v) {

                        $fileName = $v;
                        $targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
                        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"][$key][$i], $targetFilePath)) {
                            $size_str .= $fileName . ',';
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $p_size = rtrim($size_str, ",");
            $insert_query = "insert into product_image_kraft(product_id,color_id,product_images,date) values('$product_id',$k,'$p_size','$time')";
            $conslusion = $database->query($insert_query);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't put multiple values (like multiple image names) into one single column. That goes against how relational databases (like mysql) are meant to be used and will give you more headache than gain. Read up on [database normalization](https://www.essentialsql.com/get-ready-to-learn-sql-database-normalization-explained-in-simple-english/) instead. It's when you have one table for the products and another table for the images. In the image table, you only have product id and image. Then you add one row per image.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson what about the color_id

Comment: The columns were just the minimum you need. You can add more columns into the images table if needed.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i want the multiple images in one row for different color id for same product_id

Comment: Did you read the link I posted? it explains very well how you should set up the database to truly be relational.